# Trying to implement GDL in z3

Tags: c#, z3

I'm trying to implement some GDL http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_Description_Language using z3 in c# and I'm pretty much stuck in the starting blocks.

Essentially I'd like to start really simple with the following gdl

```
(role you) 
(init (state 0))

(<= (legal you proceed)
(true (state 0)))

(<= (next (state 1))
(does you proceed))

(<= terminal
(true (state 1)))

(<= (goal you 100))
```

and then query which 'legals' are satisfiable (in this contrived example there is
only one legal and it is satisfiable in the inital state)

Looking at the z3 examples it looks like I need to create a fixedpoint

```
Fixedpoint fp = ctx.MkFixedpoint();
```

and then when I want to add the fact

```
(role you)
```

I would do

```
            Sort domain=?;
            Sort range=?;
            FuncDecl pred = ctx.MkFuncDecl("role", domain, range);
            uint you = 1;
            fp.AddFact(pred, you);
```

but I don't know whether the domain should be an uninterpreted sort or something else (enum sort?). 
I'm not sure how to get the 'range' or if the symbol 'you' can just represent with integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting problem to examine. 
For the context of Z3 the following things should be kept in mind:

1. The fixedpoint engines (there are several backends at this point) 
   do not handle uninterpreted sorts or uninterpreted functions. 
   You should really just use finite domain sorts (Booleans, Bit-vectors, enumeration sorts), 
   linear arithmetic and to some extent recursive data-type sorts.
   For the concept of roles, enumeration sorts seem a better match.
   For example, player_x and player_y are two different entities.
2. For GDL, consider if there is a direct embedding of GDL to Datalog (without negation).
   Then write these as Horn clauses, e.g., a Horn clause is what the fixedpoint engine 
   calls a "rule".

Since GDL includes several built-in operations, next, goal, terminal, and init, that 
have special interpretation and the interpretations of rules in GDL do not directly
correspond to a set of Horn clauses (e.g., as far as I gather, "next" is synchronous)
it is probably easiest to first understand GDL semantics using a transition system,
that updates a vector of state variables, and then extract Horn clauses from the transition
system (an example of converting transition systems to Horn clauses are given on http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/tutorial/fixedpoints)
then write down the transition system using Horn clauses/rules.

Comment: Thanks. I did manage to make some headway. But I realised that since I would need to rebuild the state each time on state transitions rather than add/delete facts/rules - it won't be efficient for my needs. It still looks very interesting and I hope to revisit in the future.